# Remove all the JTokens except for a specific path

Tags: c#, json, tree

### Problem

Let's say I have:

```
var json = JObject.Parse("imagine some large JSON here");
```

Now let's do this:

```
var subtree = json.SelectNode("root.child.grandson");
```

I care only about:

- The grandson
- All its descendants
- Ancestors in a straight line to the root (parents, their parents, etc...)

### Some solution

Great. So I came up with this method:

```
private static void KillMySiblings(JToken token)
{
    if (token.Root == token)
        return;

    var siblingsAndSelf = token.Parent.Children().ToArray();
    foreach (var sibling in siblingsAndSelf)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(sibling, token))
            continue;

        // this removes the token from its parent
        sibling.Remove();
    }
}
```

which with this code:

```
var ancestors = subtree.AncestorsAndSelf();
foreach (var ancestor in ancestors)
    KillMySiblings(ancestor);
```

does the trick.

### So why u postin'?

Because I don't like my solution and am seeking something simpler in concept and more efficient. I don't like the idea of going through potentially O(n) nodes and removing them. I feel I should extract those parents and build a new tree from them - but I don't know how to do this properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :D